# Pairwise independence does not mean independence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

**This is taken from Stat 110**

Give an example of $3$ events $A, B, C$ which are pairwise independent but not independent.

**Hint:** find an example where whether $C$ occurs is completely determined if we know whether $A$ occurred and whether $B$ occurred, but completely undetermined if we know only one of these things.

**Solution (given):** Consider two fair, independent coin tosses, and let $A$ be the event that the
first toss is Heads, $B$ be the event that the second toss is Heads, and $C$ be the
event that the two tosses have the same result.

I don't understand the hint properly. I do understand that the events are not independent since $P(A|BC) \neq P(A)$ (and similarly for $B,C$). But how exactly do the following statements:

1. ***whether $C$ occurs is completely determined if we know whether $A$ occurred and whether $B$ occurred***
2. ***whether $C$ occurs is completely undetermined if we know of only one of $A$ and $B$***

correspond to (in)dependence of the events?

Events are independent if, for a particular event, the occurrence of one or more of the other (remaining) events does not change the probability of occurrence of that particular event.

Comment: By definition $n$ events are mutually independent, when each event is independent of any combination of other events.

Comment: "completely undetermined if we know of only one of $A$ and $B$" means that $C$ is independent of $A$, and $C$ is independent of $B$, hence the three events are pairwise independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely undetermined just means C is independent of B or A by themselves:

$$P(C|A) = \frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(HH)}{P(H)}=1/2=P(C)$$

And similarly for B.

Comment: So it means, the events are independent pairwise. What does *"whether C occurs is completely determined if we know whether A occurred and whether B occurred"* mean then? I thought I understood this part, but now it seems, I didn't. (Sorry for that, I have edited my question.)

Comment: If A and B occur then we have the outcome “HH” which means C has occurred too (by definition)

Comment: No like, how does A,B determining C correspond to $P(C|AB) \neq P(C)$? I don't get it, it doesn't feel natural

Comment: Ah, I get it, nevermind. Thank you.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus awesome, in this case we can even say that $P(C|A,B)=1$

Comment: $=1$ in this case, sure. But not always, as in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence) case, right? (I assume you meant only for this case.)

Comment: @dictatemetokcus correct. But “completely determined” means the conditional probability is 0 or 1. If it is merely not independent then the probability is in $(0,1)$

Comment: I didn't know of that. But still, complete determination is not a necessity for such events to exist (as can be seen in the linked article). It's just that the instructor for this course gave that hint so as the problem is more doable, right?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus correct

Comment: I see, thank you so much. This concludes the discussion.